# Identify OpenAL default playback device name

Tags: audio, openal, openal-soft

In OpenAL (or OpenAL Soft) is it possible to get the name of the default playback device?

I wrote a simple program to dump the driver and device names on my system, which yields the lists below. OpenAL refers to *all* of these as "devices", which I think is a little confusing since some are clearly drivers, so that labeling decision is mine.

```
Drivers:
  OpenAL Soft
  Generic Software

Default driver:
  Generic Software
  (Opening "OpenAL Soft" instead)

Playback devices:
  OpenAL Soft on CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)
  OpenAL Soft on Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)
  Generic Software on CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)
  Generic Software on Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)

Capture devices:
  OpenAL Soft on CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)
  OpenAL Soft on SPDIF Interface (UR23 USB SPDIF Rx)
  CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual
  SPDIF Interface (UR23 USB SPDIF

Default capture device:
  CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual
```

You can see at the end that I can get the default capture device name via this call (I'm using OpenTK, but it's just a thin wrapper around OpenAL):

```cs
ALC.GetString(ALDevice.Null, AlcGetString.CaptureDefaultDeviceSpecifier)
```

Although `AlcGetString.DefaultDeviceSpecifier` *appears* to be the playback equivalent, it actually returns what I'm calling the driver (Generic Software). I can't figure out how to get the default from the "Playback devices" list in my output above (which in my case is "OpenAL Soft on CABLE" ... a loopback driver).

Answer (score 0):

I realized the "info" utility which ships with the OpenAL Soft driver does correctly list this value. The [source](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/master/utils/openal-info.c#L406) show's it's an extension constant, which is also available through the OpenTK wrapper.

```c
alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEFAULT_ALL_DEVICES_SPECIFIER));
```